# Wordpress Site Homepage Not Showing Ads

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I am using Wordpress on my Domain [CBSE Result 2014](http://cbse-nic.in)
I am facing an issue on it. All the post and pages are showing the ads while the homepage is blank and is not showing any ads on it. Please if you know about these kind of isse then do reply. Also, tell me that is this a Wordpress Issue or Server issue on which the domain is hosted.

Comment: I see ads on all pages. Do you use AdBlock or something?

Comment: No I am not using anything. So, I am asking for the issue as all of my pages are showing ads except the homepage. I am facing this issue from today. Earlier, my ads were showing on every page of my websites including homepage

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution of mine. This was a server issue as the server of mine was hacked and after hacking the Wordpress Charset was set to UTF-7 due to which I was facing this issue but thanks to admin of **[New Year Greetings](http://newyeargreetings.us)** who helped me a lot to get out of this issue. The issue was only due to utf-7 which should be utf-8 for wordpress as it is recommended.